# How can we invoke facebook share via php code

Tags: php, facebook, share

is it possible to invoke facebook share from php code? I mean, when any user click in an image in my web site , I would like to share that picture from his facebook account . Is it possible ? Then how can we do it ?

Thanks in advance

Sunil

Comment: In general, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ will provide most answers to this type of question.  They provide code samples and everything.

Comment: Honestly, this is pretty evil.  I'd prefer that websites not mess around with my Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here is example code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

This is to upload a photo to a users profile.

```
<?
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'fileUpload' => true,
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  $photo = './mypic.png'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
  $message = 'Photo upload via the PHP SDK!';
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
        // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
        // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
        echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   

      echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```